# VM JAXB property 'dateOfHire' is of type 'org.joda.time.LocalDate' but is not annotated with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter

Tags: isis

On JAXB I have a LocalDate property

```
@Property(editing = Editing.ENABLED)
@Getter @Setter
private LocalDate dateOfHire;
```

On my other entity I have added `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PersistentEntityAdapter.class)` they work fine, but `LocalDate` is `org.joda.time.LocalDate` so I can't add annotation into it. When I run my VM throw exception:

```
JAXB view model 'domainapp.modules.employment.dom.employee.EmployeeVM' property 'dateOfHire' is of type 'org.joda.time.LocalDate' but is not annotated with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter. The field/method must be annotated with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(org.apache.isis.schema.utils.jaxbadapters.XxxAdapter.ForJaxb.class) or equivalent.
```

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the field instead ... as per [our docs](http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugfun/ugfun.html#_ugfun_programming-model_view-models_jaxb_joda-datatypes)

Comment: IllegalAnnotationsException:
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService
  at public org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService domainapp.modules.employment.dom.employee.EmployeeRepository.repositoryService